# How to conditionally display variables with EJS

Tags: ejs

This question **may seem duplicate**, but checking out the related questions didn't give satistfying answers.
Is there a better way of outputing (writing) variables in EJS, other then the commonly suggested

```
<% if (user) { %><%= user.name %><% } %>
```

I am searching for something like

```
<% if (user) {write(user.name)} %>
```

The closest thing I found was

```
<%= user.name ? user.name : '' %>
```

in this good post from 2015: https://blog.joeandrieu.com/2013/10/16/how-to-conditionally-display-variables-with-ejs/, but this approach fails, at least in Node 10, as I get *Cannot read property 'name' of undefined*. Am I doing it wrong? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if user object is undefined. Use this:

```
<%= typeof user != 'undefined' ? user.name : '' %>
```

Alternatively you can attach your `user` object on `locals` , so you can use it this way:

```
<%= user.name ? user.name : '' %>
```

Comment: I tried the first, but I still get the "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined", as I am trying to get typeof something nonexistent :(

Comment: What exactly is "attach your user object on locals" ?

Comment: locals is an object local variables on the rendered view.  You can read more about it here http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals. For example in your case you could use `app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
});` as a middleware before your routes

Comment: I edited my answer. Check the `user` object without any property if it is undefined. It should work now

Comment: But wouldn't this mean, that I'd have to check both user, then user.name, for existence, right? What makes it worse, I could only check the second after the first is not undefined. And that is far from elegant..:(

Comment: No. It depends on your object. I suppose that a `user` object always have a `name` property. So you don't need to check for user.name, if user is defined, then it has name property.

Comment: To elaborate: I am doing error checking. To be specific, my EJS templates are looking for different errors of an "errors" object. So I don't have user.name or user.whatever, but errors.errorA, errors.errorB... Depending on the situation, errorA, errorB.. errorZ may or may not exist. If none do, "errors" object also doesn't exist.

Comment: Understood. Then you have to check both. Unless you set an errors object on locals. Basically `locals` is your solution. If you didn't read about it, i suggest you do that.